# do I need to use ws provider in order to watch events?

Tags: web3js, events

I am using web3 version 1.0 version 26, however I can't receive any events from ganache-cli and testrpc.

```
  this.Contract.events.Created({},{ fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest' }, function(error, event){ console.log(event); })
                        .on('data', function(event){
                              console.log(event);
                        })
```

this is my provider connection

```
this.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));
```

is httpprovider not working for the watch events? do I have to use ws provider?

Comment: The HttpProvider should work fine (and does, in my experience). Can you share the rest of the code (e g. where you define this.Contract and where you generate the events)?

Comment: i have another question posted here, https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/31747/can-not-receive-the-event/34606?noredirect=1#comment37736_34606, you can check this.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used version 1.0.0 yet, and I was wrong. You do indeed need to use the `WebsocketProvider`. See my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're correct that the `HttpProvider` doesn't support subscribing to events in `web3.js` 1.0.0. From https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3.html#value:

> `Object` - `HttpProvider`: The HTTP provider is deprecated, as it won’t work for subscriptions.

You will indeed need to use the `WebsocketProvider` (or `IpcProvider` for local nodes).

Comment: can ganache-cli or testrpc support ws right now or any other ways to start a testnet supporting ws

Comment: No, as far as I can tell, `ganache` doesn't support websocket connections yet. See, e.g., https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli/issues/369.

Comment: But yes, `geth` supports it, so you should be able to spin up a test network that way. (I've never done this myself.) Or you could use an existing test network like Ropsten or Rinkeby.

Answer (score 5):

I can confirm websocket connections are supported by Ganache. I used

```
  web3 = new Web3()
  const eventProvider = new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('ws://localhost:7545')
  web3.setProvider(eventProvider)
```

Comment: How did you do this in the truffle console? It won't let me import Web3

Comment: Do it in javascript code

Answer (score 3):

Subscriptions are currently also supported through the websocket API of Infura:

```
const RINKEBY_WSS = "wss://rinkeby.infura.io/ws";
var provider = new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(RINKEBY_WSS);
var web3 = new Web3(provider);
var name = 'newBlockHeaders'; // e.g.

web3.eth.subscribe(name, (error, result) => {
        if(!error) {
            console.log(result);
        } else {
            console.log('Error:', error);          
        }
    }).on("data", function (transaction) {
        console.log(transaction);
});
```

See [here](https://infura.io/docs/wss/introduction) for the documentation.